# Can I add an explorer shortcut to solution explorer and have it actually function?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-explorer

I'd like to be able to include shortcuts in my solution explorer so that I can just double click in solution explorer to open a directory related to the project or solution, is this possible? Currently if I add a shortcut to the solution it comes up as a .lnk file and it opens insides Visual studio as a binary file instead of opening in windows explorer.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2005/2008 you can right click on any folder or project in the Solution Explorer and "Open Folder In Windows Explorer, does that help?

Comment: When you add an item to the solution/project it copies it local instead of just referencing that item, so I don't think that would do anything for being able to jump to a location in explorer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it may not be the most elegant answer and does not answer your question directly, have you considered adding a HTML file to your solution and inside that HTML page you place your links. You should be able to link directly to files, folders, web content, etc...

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is per this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18163825/180430

Basically you right click on your .lnk file and choose "Open With".

Choose **Add** to add a new program/editor. The program to add is `C:\Windows\System32\explorer.exe` (or similar).

Then set that to be the default editor for .lnk files.